# How to convert date stored in nvarchar to date in MMDDYYY format removing dashes (e.g 06122012)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to convert date stored as `nvarchar` in `Birth_date` column SQL.

For example, currently I have dates in `1999-01-22` format, I want to convert it to `01221999` (8 characters) using SQL Server.

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: If I were you, I would convert them to `DATE` right away ! Don't use Yet Another wrong data type for this ...

Comment: `ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD ProperBirthDate DATE; UPDATE dbo.YourTable SET ProperBirthDate = CAST(Birth_date AS DATE);` and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @marc_s that you should probably be using the proper data type (date), but if you really have to return this as your custom format, we can make good use of [`convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
select replace(convert(varchar(10), convert(date, Birth_date), 101), '/', '')
```

I suggest that it's a code smell that `convert` doesn't even have the format you're looking for. We must therefore massage the converted data, in this case using `replace` to remove slashes.

Comment: Thanks but I am getting " Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for divide operator" error

Comment: This happens with just the `select` I've provided? You might want to post some example data and your full code (enough to duplicate the error).